# Location of java generated code from jsp in Eclipse environment

Tags: jsp, debugging

I'm using Eclipse Java EE IDE , Version Oxygen.3a Release 4.7.3a. 
When i write a jsp file, the java code is generated under the folder of my workspace :

```
.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\
```

It's possible to setup Eclipse to generated them under the folder of Tomcat:

```
work\Catalina\localhost
```

In Eclipse isn't possible to debug these generated classes ?

Thanks.